# What it means when PM(K) of ps gets negative values?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, powershell

I got the following negative PM (The amount of pageable memory that the process is using, in kilobytes) values when execute the `ps` command. What it means when the values are negative?

```
PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   5947    4145 -1218888    1537304   981 ...50.77   8344 sqlservr


PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   6060    4172 -1218876    1537316   981 ...52.08   8344 sqlservr


PS H:\> ps sqlservr

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
   6481    4258 -1218832    1537376   981 ...56.55   8344 sqlservr
```

The negative value may be the overflow of `Int32`? However, the following statements shows that the paged memory was 4TB? Which is not possible.

```
$m = [int32]::MaxValue
($m + ($m -1218832) + 2)/1024/1024
# returns 4094.83763122559 (GB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative values can appear if the page file has grown at some point in the past, and has since shrunk. SQL Server uses lots of memory and pages a lot, so this type of behavior is pretty common for SQL Server.

Edit: This could also be because of the size of Int32... in which case, use the provided 64-bit property:

```
ps sqlserver | select WorkingSet64
```

or

```
ps sqlserver | select PagedMemorySize64
```

Most of the memory properties have corresponding 64-bit versions for this reason.